# Reading the data from socket is currupted in following condition?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, visual-c++, mfc

I am reading data from a socket packet by packet and writing into another buffer to combined all the data.

```
BOOL _ReadPacket(PBYTE BufferRead, DWORD &Length, SOCKET Socket)
{
    WSABUF Buffer;
    DWORD Flags = 0;
    int Result = 0;
    FILE *file;
    Buffer.buf = (char *)BufferRead;
    Buffer.len = Length;
    Flags = 0;
    Result = WSARecv(Socket, &Buffer, 1, &Length, &Flags, NULL, NULL);

    // if ((file=fopen("D:/test/test1/test1.txt","a+") ) != NULL)
    //{ 
    //UINT val = Buffer.len;
    //fprintf(file, "%d\n", val);
    //
    //fflush(file);
    //fclose(file);
    //}
    return(Result != SOCKET_ERROR);
}
```

Uncommenting the commented code fixes the problem. Why do I get corrupt data when I leave the code commented out?

Comment: Are you sure `BufferRead` is legit?  Do you get errors from `WSARecv`?  Did you `WSAInitialize` (or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

The fourth argument of WSARecv should be a pointer to the number of bytes received. However, you are passing the address of a pointer to the length of your buffer.

If you were passing the pointer, and not a pointer to a pointer, then it would be weird but it should work fine (as it won't corrupt anything). As it is now, however, it is probably writing where it shouldn't.

In short: Check and fix the fourth parameter.